# Face Detection - Open CV

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

I used opencv face-detection sample android project to detect faces. Can I focus on detected face area in camera preview and focus that region using Android APIs?
Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: It's giving me error as the camera is being used by another object of class Camera. I made a new method in JavaCameraView class called focus(List<Areas> focusareas) which will set camera parameters to focus on a region. Can someone guide me how to call this method from Fdactivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

get the face area and show it in imageview in android. opencv gives the area of the face detected.

Comment: I want to focus the detected area. Then take picture for that view.

Comment: It's giving me error as the camera is being used by another object of class Camera. I made a new method in JavaCameraView class called focus(List<Areas> focusareas) which will set camera parameters to focus on a region. Can someone guide me how to call this method from Fdactivity.java